# How do I get my Telegram bot to write in monospace?

Tags: python, formatting, telegram-bot

I am trying to write something in "monospace" with my telegram bot using the following Python function:

````
@bot.message_handler(commands=['test_monospace'])
def test_monospace(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "```This message should be in monospace```")
````

Unfortunately, when I test the bot I get the message without the monospace formatting

[image: The bot output]

How can I get it to use monospace?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the `parse_mode` to `MarkdownV2`:

````
bot.reply_to(message, "```This message should be in monospace```", parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
````

You could also use the [`telegram.Message.reply_markdown_v2`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_markdown_v2) shortcut.

---

[image]